# Convert Negative String into Float in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I haven't seen any questions on StackOverflow that pertain to this question specifically in Kotlin. I am getting a crash

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "−0.15"
```

when I try `string.toFloat()`, what is the best solution in Kotlin?

Comment: Conversion functions should work just fine on negative numbers.  Just tested it to double check.  Are you sure the string is what you think it is?  Are you sure there isn't extra data, or a non-standard character for - or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) sign isn't ordinary [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) symbol, replace your minus sign to the normal one:

```kotlin
"−0.15".replace("−", "-").toFloat()
```

Comment: holy moly - im gonna have to have a chat with the backend guys ... thanks Vadik!